# Migrating a solution from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, migration

I had a problem while migrating a solution from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2015, in my solution using DirectX June 2010, but as far as I know DirectX is integrated into the Windows SDK, which should lead to a definition  again.  Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem of mine. Thanks.

Comment: The simpest answer is to recreate your project afresh rather than trying to migrate it. Migration sometimes causes more problems than its worth.

Comment: I cannot  recreate the solution again because my solution includes a lot of projects, if recreating it will take more time and it is unlikely that it will work properly.

Comment: If that's the case then you are in a bad place. If its a big complex project it's unlikely that migration will work either, even without the DirectX issue.

Comment: It seems that Visual Studio 2015 uses the Windows SDK as the default. This led to a conflict with the DirectX SDK. I just want to use DirectX without using the Windows SDK to resolve this conflict?

Comment: The DirectX SDK is integrated into the Windows SDK (as I think you know) so you should be using the Windows SDK. If there are any conflicts between your code and the Windows SDK then the correct thing to do is fix the problems in your code, not to try and keep the DirectX SDK.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but modifying the code seems complicated, because my code uses libraries that the Windows SDK doesn't support anymore, such as D3DX. Since I'm migrating, not creating, I want to stay as present as possible. If there is no other way I will consider modifying this code.